# VBA copy from sheet to another based on condition

Tags: vba, excel

I have a set of data from one table in a sheet range being H11:BG25. I want to run a bit of code to look into each column and if the sum of that col is > 0, then copy the whole range for that column. If the sum is < 0, do nothing. So far I have the following code but it does not copy the range it only copies non 0 values.

```
Sub CopyActuals()

For iCol = 8 To 59
For iRow = 11 To 25

  With Worksheets("Project - Actual (Hours)").Cells(iRow, iCol)
    ' Check that cell is not empty.

        If 'Condition to be if there is any data in the rows 11-25 for each column, then copy the whole column

        Else
                Worksheets("Project - Actual (Hours)").Cells(iRow, iCol).Copy
                Worksheets("Project - Budget (Hours)").Cells(iRow, iCol).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Worksheets("Project - Budget (Hours)").Cells(iRow, iCol).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

        End If

End With

    Next iRow
Next iCol

End Sub
```

Comment: you could check for the last row which has data. If the lastrow is bigger than 25 or is 25 then do something. The last row can be found by "lastrow = Activeworkbook.Activesheet.Cells(Activeworkbook.ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row"

Comment: if you Add "Dim Sht1 As Worksheet   Sht1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")" then you could replace the "activeworbook.Activeworksheet" by "Sht1"

Comment: Thanks, I guess my problem is that I want it to copy the entire column from rows 11:25 as opposed to non 0 values only.

Comment: Correct me if im wrong. Your expecation is to copy a column if the sum of all value in the column is grater than 0. Am i right?

Comment: Hi Siva, yes correct.

Comment: Ok then you could also check for the last column which contains data "LastCol = Sht1.Cells(1, Sht1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column" then loop through the columns "for Col = 1 To LastCol" "If lastrow > 25 Then" "Sht1.Range("A11:" & Col & "25").Copy" and then paste it on the other sheet.

Comment: Chris u want to check & copy the rows from 11-25 only in the respective columns?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CopyActuals()
Dim ActlSheet As Worksheet
Dim BbgtSheet As Worksheet
Dim rowCount As Integer
Dim SumValue As Integer
Dim rng As Range
Set ActlSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Project - Actual (Hours)")
Set BbgtSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Project - Budget (Hours)")
rowCount = ActlSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
For iCol = 8 To 59
 Set rng = Range(Cells(11, iCol), Cells(rowCount, iCol))
 SumValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng)
 If (SumValue > 0) Then
     rng.Select
     rng.Copy
     'put your next action
 Else
     'put your next action
 End If
Next iCol

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Siva in his code, he also defining range for rows as well 11 to 25, hope your missing it :)

Comment: You are right :). I just thought to have it as dynamic so that even if some new rows are entered, then also code should work.